# I want to return the value of the numbers across the top and side of my grid by looking up a number in the grid

Tags: excel-365

[image: Number Grid]

I have this number grid, and I want to look up the value 12 and return the 1 and the 2.  essentially the row and col.
With this, I can also look up 32 in the grid, then calculate the distance between the two, once I have the coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Found most of a solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1387440/formula-to-search-for-an-integer-value-in-a-range-2d-grid

Had to modify the formulas a little, I think there was a typo.

point 1 x =SMALL(IF($EW3=$B$4:$ES$153, ROW($B$4:$ES$153)-ROW($B$4)), ROW(1:1))
where my grid lives in B4:E153, I was looking up the number in cell EW3.

point 1 y =SMALL(IF($EW3=$B$4:$ES$153, COLUMN($B$4:$ES$153)-COLUMN($B$4)), ROW(1:1))

This gives me a 0 based return.  So the first row will be 0, same for the col.
I can also find a second point and even calculate the Manhattan distance, and drag the formula.